# JPA : Could not locate TransactionManager

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I'm using JPA 2 in a JSF 2 project, so I configure my data source in the GlassFish v3, everything is fine, but if I try to test JPA queries in the Hibernate Tools it gives me the follow error:

```
Sessionfactory error:Could not locate TransactionManager
```

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="SuaParte" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/suaparte_ds</jta-data-source>
        <class>entity.Area</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
        </properties>


    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I'm using EclipseLink 2.3 (Indigo) and JPA 2 in my Eclipse JSF 2 project.

**EDIT**
Follow @fonini approach, my hibernate.properties:

```
hibernate.connection.username=<filled>
hibernate.connection.password=<filled>
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.connection.url=<filled>
hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider
hibernate.datasource=jdbc/suaparte_ds
hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class=org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup
```

But now gives me another error:
[image: error]

Did I have to change the `id generator` in my entities ?

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="product")
    public class Product implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        private Integer id;

        @Size(max=150, message="150 caracteres no máximo")
        private String description;

        // getters and setter
}
```

Comment: If you deploy your project to a Glassfish Server, it works?

Comment: it does @fonini, I just to test the JPQL queries and found out that Hibernate Tools is capable of this.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have sequences, it works with auto-increment. You must change the GenerationType.SEQUENCE to GenerationType.IDENTITY

Comment: I've never used Hibernate Tools in combination with JPA (Eclipse for Java EE's builtin Dali plugin is more than sufficient), so I can't tell from experience, but I wonder if it would really work while you're using EclipseLink implementation of JPA instead of Hibernate's implementation of JPA. I wouldn't be surprised if that that won't work together at all.

Comment: @fonini I made the changes as you suggest but still gives me the original error

Comment: @BalusC, How do I install (or some explained link) this Dali Plugin ? I think it is already in Eclipse Java EE Indigo version, but I never used this one before, so I don't know how to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Since Hibernate Tools run inside Eclipse, it doesn't have access to Application server specific datasources.

You can use a properties file to setup connection that will override the datasource.

Here's an example file:

```
hibernate.connection.username=user
hibernate.connection.password=pass
hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.PostgreSQL.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:postgresql...

hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider
hibernate.datasource=
hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class=
```

Comment: How would stay if was in MySQL ? I'm using MySQL, sorry didn't mention before =)

Comment: Dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect. If you're using InnoDB (org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect), if you're using MyISAM (org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect). Driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost/your_db. Hope this helps!